# Automapper, AfterMap not triggered when mapping on existing object if ConstructUsing is mentionned

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I'm facing an issue when `AfterMap` is not triggered.

Here are the conditions for this issue to occur:

- I want to map values on an existing object from its abstract base type
- `ConstructUsing` is provided as it is here where the concrete type will be chosen

Here the whole xunit (after doing `dotnet new xunit -o PbAutoMapper`) test:

```cs
using System;
using AutoMapper;
using Xunit;

namespace PbAutoMapper
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
            {
                config.CreateMap<SourceClass, BaseDestinationClass>()
                    .ConstructUsing(this.Construct)
                    .ForMember(i => i.MyNewProperty, o => o.Ignore())
                    .AfterMap(this.AfterMap);
                config.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>();
            });
            var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
            var src = new SourceClass { MyProperty = 1 };
            var dest = mapper.Map<BaseDestinationClass>(src);
            Assert.Equal("1", dest.MyNewProperty); // This works...
            dest = new DestinationClass();
            mapper.Map(src, dest);
            Assert.Equal("1", dest.MyNewProperty); // This failed because AfterMap wasn't triggered
        }
        private DestinationClass Construct(SourceClass s, ResolutionContext ctx)
        {
            var d = new DestinationClass();
            ctx.Mapper.Map(s, d, ctx);
            return d;
        }
        private void AfterMap(SourceClass s, BaseDestinationClass d)
        {
            d.MyNewProperty = s.MyProperty.ToString();
        }
    }
    public class SourceClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class BaseDestinationClass
    {
        public string MyNewProperty { get; set; }
    }
    public class DestinationClass : BaseDestinationClass
    {
    }
}
```

Note: this code that seems to be implementable differently is actually over simplified to reveal my problem in the easiest way.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: I know this page by heart... the example is over simplified compared to my implementation. The implementation needs it to be this way for some other reasons I won't explain here.

Comment: If that doesn't help, you can look at the tests in the repo to find out how things work.

Comment: My pb is not about how to use inheritance. As I mentioned, I have a specific need that compels me to do it this way. Here, I just want my AfterMap to be triggered.

Comment: It seems to me that's _exactly_ your problem. But other than the docs and the tests, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: as I mentioned, I use very efficiently everything that is described in this page in the rest of my application. I just have one specific case that needs my implementation to be done this way. My question is not "how to implement mapping for  inheritance?" as I know very well how to use it. My ONLY question is "why my AfterMap is not triggered in this specific case?"

Comment: You know that mapping can be written manually ;)